# How to save a file in bits using java?

Tags: java, file, file-io, bit, huffman-code

right now I am working on a project for text compression using Huffman coding. I am able to read in a file(containing ASCII text) and create a Huffman encoded message. For example if my file `"input.txt"` contains the following text:
`Missippi river`, then my encoded code word would be something like this
`1110100110111001001010000110101111001110` which has 40 bits, whereas my `"input.txt"` was 14 bytes(14*8 = 112 bits). So I have reduced 112 bits to 40 bits, but how do I output my code word (containing O's and 1's) to a file which is only 40 bits long? I tried putting this string into a `.txt.` file, but that `.txt.` file ended up being even more longer than my `"input.txt"` thereby rendering my entire project worthless. I am trying to create a encoder/decoder model. I have successfully created the encoder part and I am able to create the Huffman code word as well, but how do I output this so that my decoder can read it and decompress.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you store bits as a string?

Comment: I got it from a tree, so using a string seemed easy. Later on I used a BitSet to convert it to int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of a string of 0's and 1's, you could use a [java BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) to store the 1/0's as boolean bits, and then when you write it, you'd use `toByteArray` to write the bytes directly as a binary file, instead of writing a string of text.

Comment: I actually used a BitSet and I serialized BitSet's object which ended up being more larger than my actual input. Would the `toByteArray` be same?

Comment: @rohitkrishna094 No, serialization is designed for slightly different purpose (storing data such that it can be turned automatically back to an object). If you write bytes directly it will be far more efficient (since simply bytes are stored, and not the internal parameters/state of BitSet)

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks, but could you give me a link or a small code snippet that explains how the byte array works.

Comment: the basic idea is that the bitset is also a set of 1010101010101's, but stored in an object that makes it easier to program against.  but when you turn that into bytes, you pack 8 bits into each byte.  so each 8 ones or zeros (16 bytes a string in java?) would turn into just 1 byte when serialized as a byte array.